# Cron Job Python Script

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, cron, sh

Before yesterday I have had no experience in linux or python.  I am a Visual C# developer by trade so please keep that in mind when responding.

I have setup a CRON job in linux (ubuntu server) which executes a shell script which calls a python script.  The python script works great in terminal.  The cron job is calling the shell script (I have output).

After spending about 10 hours on google trying to figure out why it seemingly does not call the python script I decided to look at the import statement.  There are 4, one of which is not a python library but a third-party python library.  For whatever reason when I run the program it picks up the library in the import statement no problem.  However when the cron job calls the import it must not be able to locate it.

My batch script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/bin
echo "start"
/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/checkit.py
```

both the checkit.py and the import.py are in /usr/local/bin.  Both are chmod 775.  What else do I need to do in able to get cron to see it?  The program works fine when I call it, another script I wrote which doesn't use anything third party works fine in cron job.  The only thing I can figure is that python cant locate the import .py file when executing the program

Sorry if I have been not so clear, this is all new too me.

Comment: The python code itself is probably relevant. Does `. script.bsh` work?

Comment: sorry, what is script.bsh?

Comment: Whatever your bash script is named

Comment: the bash script runs, I see output in the log... when I take out the import [[class]] in the python file the script executes and I can see the first print statement, obviously the rest fails because its dependent on that import.  When I leave the import statement there I get no output from the python script, no errors anywhere... just dies.

Comment: if I just run the script from console, everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your assistance.  I did finally find the solution.  I am not sure why it did not work with everyones solutions before but I am guessing this is comes down to my ignorance of linux and python.  I probably missed something that would be complete common sense to everyone else.

basically in my main python script I told it where to find the 3rd party module explicitly but doing the following:

```
import imp

myclass = imp.load_source('myclass', '/usr/local/bin/myclass.py')
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Linux command line, run this:

```
echo $PATH
```

Take the output that you see and put it in your cron script where it currently says "PATH=/usr/local/bin". It might now look something like:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin
```

cron does not necessarily have access to your environment variables. By doing this, you're telling it explicitly.

[Edited] Also tell cron to explicitly cd into the directory where the script is. The cron file line will now look something like:

```
10 10 * * * cd /home/keht/directoryname && /home/keht/batchscript
```

Replace /home/keht/directoryname above with the full path of the directory where your batch script resides and replace /home/keht/batchscript with the full path of your batch script. (The 10 10 *** is just for example.Change it to what you want.)

Comment: keht@ubuntu:/usr/local/bin$ echo $path <-- this returns a blank line

Comment: It has to be exactly as shown. All upper case - 'PATH' and not 'path'

Comment: Right! sorry, I caught on to that after I posted...

so this in the terminal is: /home/keht/bin:/home/keht/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

I added that to the PATH variable.  cron still failed.